# Does opening credit cards at different banks impact credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit-history

I have been building credit with a card for about 6 years while I went through school.  My credit score is decent so I'm looking into opening another card to take advantage of cash back deals and increase my max credit.  My current bank has a tempting offer for a cash back card, but there are other options out there.  All other things being equal I'd prefer to go with the same institution for the sake of convenience.

**Is there any difference in building credit score between 2 cards at one bank and 2 cards at 2 banks?**

Comment: Not to FICO and the credit bureaus: an unsecured card from Bank A is as unsecured as a card from Bank B.  (Having said that, I prefer the 1.5% CC from the same bank I have my checking account, rather than a 2% card somewhere else "for the sake of convenience".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your credit score is currently calculated by both your bank and an external credit bureau (like Equifax, Experian and Transunion).

So on the paper it should not make any difference towards your credit score if you have made it with only one entity or more, as all the information is gathered by those external institutions.

But, depending on the relationship you have built with your current bank, you may obtain better deals as they already know you.